# ASP.NET storing user search results

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am relatively new to asp.net, and was wondering if anybody could help with my current problem.

I am creating a website which will allow people to search through a database for different users. This search can be done through different categories, i.e. first name, surname etc. When the user presses the search button, they get a grid view with a unique ID, first name and last name. I have converted the unique ID into a hyperlink to a user details page. The hyperlink stores the text of the unique ID, so for example 1234 will be saved at the end of the hyperlink. I done this using the following code...

```
hl.NavigateUrl = "~/UserInfo.aspx?UniqueID="
                        + id.ToString();
```

When the User info page loads, I then take this unique ID and use an SQLDataReader to find all of the information based on this unique ID from the database and display it in corresponding textboxes on page load. The text boxes are not enabled.

The user can then click on an edit button, the text boxes will become enabled and they can then change this information and update the database.

My problem was that when I did this, because the page had to reload everytime the button was clicked, nothing in the database changed because it was getting the origional search information back each time.

To resolve this, I then added in if (!Page.IsPostBack). This resolved the problem and everyone could update the database as and when they pleased. However, now I have a new problem because when the user navigates from the user information page, to a tab which shows different information about the same user, if they navigate back, this information is lost, because the page no longer has the unique ID, so all of my text boxes are blank.

I have looked online, and have tried putting the user id into a session, and have looked at caching the data, however the information I found was not helpful for my situation.

Does anybody know how I can over come this problem without messing up my update database function?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*everyone could update the database*" when the database get updated, and with what?

Comment: put the unique ID in session

Comment: Can you keep the id in the tab urls?

Comment: Are you on the same page when a user drills down to view their details? If you are, stick the UserID in ViewState. Or in Session. Or in a hidden field. Wherever you like, really. If on a different page, put the UserId in session. If the session has timed out by the time they get back - detect the session is null and send them to a log in page. Or pick up their log in details from cookies. Depends how secure you need to be.

Comment: They just change user information, for example, name, email address etc. I tried putting it in a session, but wasn't sure how to get it back again? I have discovered that if you navigate back using the browser back key it works, however, if you just click on the user details button, it clears the page. How would you go about adding the user ID into a view state? Sorry I really dont know much about all this sort of stuff in asp.net

Comment: Also, @MartinSmellworse the log in will be from an administrator, and the unique ID will be from one of the users, so the log in details wont be useful when stored in cookies

Comment: Finally got this to work, using `HttpContext.Current.Session`